# How do I display a count of null values for field selected in combobox?

Tags: ms-access-2003

I've tried using DCOUNT and SQL and nothing is working. I've pasted both queries below. When I run the SQL nothing appears in the listbox. When I run the DLOOKUP I get the error message "Run-time error '2001": You canceled the previous operation. The combobox name is ScrubbedList. Table is named Scrubbed.

DCOUNT

```
Dim strScrubbedValue As String
strScrubbedValue = Me.ScrubbedList
Dim intCountNull As Integer

intCountNull = DCount("*", "Scrubbed", "IsNull" & strScrubbedValue)
Text267 = intCountNull
```

SQL

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strScrubbedValue As String

strScrubbedValue = Me.ScrubbedList
strSQL = "SELECT Count(*) As CountAll" & strScrubbedValue & " FROM Scrubbed"
strSQL = strSQL + "WHERE" & strScrubbedValue = ""
Me.List265.RowSource = strSQL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 intCountNull = DCount("*", "Scrubbed", "SomeField Is Null")
```

So for the combo:

```
 intCountNull = DCount("*", "Scrubbed", strScrubbedValue & " Is Null")
```

It is important to ensure that you have included relevant spaces when concatenating strings.

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strScrubbedValue As String

strScrubbedValue = Me.ScrubbedList
strSQL = "SELECT Count(*) As CountAll " & strScrubbedValue & " FROM Scrubbed"
strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE " & strScrubbedValue & " Is Null"
Me.List265.RowSource = strSQL
```

Note that Null and zero-length strings (ZLS) are not the same.

To get both, you can say:

```
    strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE " & strScrubbedValue & " & '' = ''"
```

The string concatenator in VBA is &, not +. The plus sign must be used with care, because it can lead to unexpected nulls.